# Registry Edit From Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-7, registry, regedit

I would like to change the registry path's value from 0 to 1:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\LogonUI\Background\OEMBackground
```

Is there any possible way of doing this within a batch file using the "reg" command? You can grab the syntax [here](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html). I searched it, but can not find a way to modify it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stay away from reg.exe, it can be blocked by a policy. I suggest to use wmic.exe.
In your case it should works like this:

```
setlocal
:: $KEY broken for better readability
set "$KEY=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"
set "$KEY=%$KEY%\Authentication\LogonUI\Background"
set "$VALNAME=OEMBackground"
set "VAL=1"
set "HIVE=&H80000001"                 &:: "&H80000001 = HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"
wmic.exe /NAMESPACE:\\root\default Class StdRegProv Call^
    SetDWORDValue^
    hDefKey="%HIVE%"^
    sSubKeyName="%$KEY%"^
    sValueName="%$VALNAME%"^
    uValue="%VAL%"^
    && echo Success.||echo failed.
endlocal
```

To select another registry-hive, the value of hDefKey must be changed accordingt to this [MSDN-Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393297%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
Other Methods for different value types which can be used instead of SetDWORDValue can be found there as well.

Comment: wmic could equally well be blocked surely. Much easier to use reg.

Comment: It certainly depends on where you want to use it. In corporate environments RegistryTools are usually blocked by a GroupPolicy. wmic not so much...

Comment: I'd question "usually".  Perhaps I'm being overly optimistic, but since blocking registry tools serves no useful purpose, I'd hope that it isn't particularly common!  In any case, since this OP asked for a solution using `reg` I think we can take it for granted that he is able to use it.